# Find Duplicate rows from df. Python

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

```
df = 

Name    Age City
Jack    34  Sydney
Riti    30  Delhi
Aadi    16  New York
Riti    30  Delhi
Riti    30  Delhi
Riti    30  Mumbai
Aadi    40  London
Sachin  30  Delhi
```

```
df[df.duplicated(keep='last')]
```

The above code gives the list of duplicated. But what I need is if the `df` contains atleast 1 duplicate, then it should return `The df contains duplicate rows`.

Comment: Hi, When sharing a DF, could please paste a format that is directly usable by others ? Like a dict or other, to avoid us to rewrite it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `any`:

```
>>> df
     Name  Age     City
0    Jack   34   Sydney
1    Riti   30    Delhi
2    Aadi   16  NewYork
3    Riti   30    Delhi
4    Riti   30    Delhi
5    Riti   30   Mumbai
6    Aadi   40   London
7  Sachin   30    Delhi
>>> df.duplicated().any()
True
>>> 'The df contains duplicates' if df.duplicated().any() else 'no duplicates' 
'The df contains duplicates'
```

Answer (score 1):

**duplicated** actually returns a Series containing boolean values for each row. If the row has a duplicate then the corresponding row in the returned Series has a "True" value.

Hence, you can do the below:

```
df.duplicated().any()
```

It will return True if there is any duplicate in your DataFrame.